# Reset ink level on HP DeskJet 2622

Tags: printer

Currently I have refilled my 304XL cartriges for the first time on my printer. Everytihing worked fine as I had 40+ printed papers on them however, after the catrtiges reached 50 papers,  it shows an Cartrige error on both cartriges. If I hold the Power button and press Cancel, it resets the ink levels, print a test page (everything looks ok) and then, the ink levels go back to Cartrige Error.

Can't print anything. Every time I try to print, I get an error that the printer needs attention. I think this printer had enough attention from me in the past two days...

Is there a way to permanently reset the ink level counter on a refilled cartrige?

Comment: Unfortunately printers are too smart for their own good. What’s worse is the ink has a chip that indicates it’s empty and the printer can read that.  It’s not as simple as just putting more ink in the cartridge

Comment: I know. On some old printers you could get away by using tape over some pins. My question was not "why" because I already know why this happens. My question is "how", if there is any way.

Comment: Refilled or replace the cartridges?

Comment: Even more unfortunately, **HP has DRM that disables printing**  https://www.howtogeek.com/403346/hps-ink-subscription-has-drm-that-disables-your-printer-cartridges/ . If you want to replace ink yourself, get an inkjet with tanks, such as the Epson EcoTank line.

Comment: As far as I know, in 2017 there was an class action lawsuit against HP for preveinting users to refill the cartriges and the outcome was that HP would allow the users to refill the cartriges but it will warn the user that the cartriges are tampered with. What happend? Doesn’t this apply?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik also, my cartriges were not part of a subscription. I have bought them from Argos. Once I had aprox, 45 pages printed on them, I recharged them and now that they reached 50 pages, I get that "Cartrige Problem" error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you cannot. Chips, DRM, and a variety of other methods are used by the ink manufacturer to prevent this from being done.

Comment: In 2017 there was an class action lawsuit against HP for preveinting users to refill the cartriges and the outcome was that HP would allow the users to refill the cartriges but it will warn the user that the cartriges are tampered with. What happend? Doesn’t this apply?

Comment: Also, wouldn't work if I were to buy a 3rd party refillable 304XL cartrige?